# Does this upper triangular matrix have a specific name?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Does the following matrix have a specific name?

$$A(a,r)=\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
        0 & r & 2ar & 3a^2r \\
        0 & 0 & r^2 & 3ar^2 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & r^3
    \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Italian wikipedia calls them Pascal matrices, but it appears that in English and French literature Pascal matrices are only your $A(1,1)$.

Comment: In the examples in the italian page, when mentioning about the group $T(h,d)$ it also shows the relation with a Vandermonde vector. Do you know if a Vandermonde vector remains still a Vandermonde vector IFF the transformation is Pascal?

Comment: No, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Upper Pascal Matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) (generalized) seems to fit the description.

Comment: Do you know if a Vandermonde vector remains still a Vandermonde vector IFF the transformation is Pascal?